# Single-spa - Registering application

Tags: javascript, typescript, single-spa

I'm fairly new with `Javascript`/`Typescript` and was developing a Single-Spa with [Single SPA Router](https://single-spa.js.org)
Searching for info about registering applications I found different ways of doing that, one way is using the LayoutEngine that "automatically" register my applications this way:

```js
const routes = constructRoutes(microfrontendLayout);
const applications = constructApplications({routes, loadApp({name}) {
   return System.import(name);
}});

const layoutEngine = constructLayoutEngine({ routes, applications }); 
applications.forEach(registerApplication);
layoutEngine.activate();
```

From what I understood is, in microfrontend-layout.html we have to put something like an HTML tag in this way

```
<application name="@prueba-organizacion/micro-prueba-app1"></application>
```

with that and having an importmap in index.ejs the app was loading fine.

But then I found another way, the manually way:

A)

```js
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";
registerApplication({
     name: '@prueba-organizacion/micro-prueba-app1',
     app: () => System.import('@prueba-organizacion/micro-prueba-app1'),
     activeWhen: (location) => location.pathname.startsWith('/app1')
});
start();
```

But that says: `Promise\<System.Module\>` is not assignable to type `Application\<{}\>`

Then I found ANOTHER WAY of doing the same as above:

B)

```
System.import('single-spa').then(({ registerApplication, start }) => {
   registerApplication({
     name: '@prueba-organizacion/micro-prueba-app1',
     app: () => System.import('@prueba-organizacion/micro-prueba-app1'),
     activeWhen: (location) => location.pathname.startsWith('/app1'),
   });
   start();
});
```

The thing here is, what's the difference between point A) and point B)?
I mean, they're importing the modules and registerApplication, start functions but one of them is throwing me an error.

I'm using "single-spa": "^5.9.3" from `package.json`

Thanks!

I've tried both ways, one of them is not working, the other one is working (B) as expected